# Display list Items from top to bottom in a list view

Tags: java, android

I have a master-detail work flow. The effect i'm attempting to achieve is this:
 When I select an item in the master list view it displays items from top to bottom in the details list view instead of in an arbitrary fashion. By arbitrary, What I mean is I choose an item in from my master list view then in my details list view it displays all the text items first then all the images i.e An image will be displayed in the 3rd list row of the list view then maybe the 5th row then maybe the first row and so on. Instead of what a really want which is text and an image displayed in the 1st row;then the text and an image in the 2nd row;then text and an image in the 3rd row and so on and so forth. Can anyone help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will have to make:

1. A main layout, that one will contain the two listViews(master and detail).
2. The master listView need to have a setOnItemClickListener that will trigger the method for populate the detail when some item has being clicked, in case that you want something custom you will have  to create a custom arrayAdapter and layout for it.
3. A custom Layout for the detail listView, when I said custom Layout I mean a normal Layout that will have the rows with all the view that you described and later you will inflate to the detail listView also you will have to make a custom arrayAdapter.

Note:

For inflate the custom Layouts  you will have to make a custom arrayAdapter. Check the next link: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

Comment: Thank you Otejada92 but that is not what I meant :(

Comment: @ronaldmonkeymanovich sorry I thought you needed ideas to achieve the functionality that you described, now I ask you, what do you meant with your post? because you do not have any problem with a existing code, right? and if you have problem with your app upload the code, that way the community could help you.